# Unable to change Profile Picture Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, profile-picture

I am able to store the image in desired location but I am unable to view it.
When the page is reloaded ,the same default image appears .
Default image never changes to my desired Image.

My Controller File(UserController.php):

```
     public function update_avatar(Request $request)
    {

      if($request->hasFile('avatar'))

      {

            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/src/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));


      }

      return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }




}
```

My Route file:

```
Route::post('/dashboard',[
                'uses'=>'UserController@update_avatar',

                ]);
```

My view File:

```
<form action="/dashboard" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>

    <input type="file" name="avatar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-md-5"  >

    <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary " value="submit">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{Session::token() }}" name="_token">
    <a href="#">Remove</a>

    </div>


        <div id="main">
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()"><img src="download.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="Placeholder image"></span>
</div>

      </form>
```

Comment: it looks like you're prepending a timestamp to the filename, so I'm curious how you reference that in your view

Comment: here you go ...and don't worry I will give up vote and the tick .to right answer..this is my second account i'm not a newbie....:)

Comment: @VishwasSaxena where exactly are you calling the src of the image in your view file? can you show that part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Are you not saving the uploaded Image to the Database? Are you only uploading images to the dedicated Images Folder but not saving it to the Database? If you want, you can do this in your controller:

```
    <?php

        public function update_avatar(Request $request){
            $avatarURI = null;
            if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {

                $avatar     = $request->file('avatar');
                $filename   = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
                Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/src/uploads/avatars/' . $filename));
                $avatarURI  = "src/uploads/{$filename}";
                User::update();
            }

            // YOU MAY NEED TO PERSIST THIS IN THE DATABASE
            // TO UPDATE THE avatar:

            $usr = new \App\User();
            $usr->update(['avatar' => $avatarURI, 'id'=>$userID]); //<== ID OF THE USER TO BE UPDATED...
            return redirect()->route('dashboard', ['imgURI'=>$avatarURI, 'user'=>$usr]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change user with avatar attribute suit your need

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
    {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $path = '/src/uploads/avatars/';
        $filename = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path($path . $filename));
        $request->user()->avatar = $filename;
        $request->user()->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: I am not taking any user in consideration ,sir